# Unable to add camel archetype in a maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-camel

I am using Eclipse (**Kepler Service Release 1**). I tried to create a New Maven Project and in Filter tried to locate the camel archetype. Since it was not there I clicked on Add Archetype and tried to add the `camel-archetype-java` and used the following values,

```
groupId:org.apache.camel.archetypes
artifactId:camel-archetype-java
version:2.12.1
URL:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact
```

After using the above values and clicking ok, I am getting the below exception

```
Can't resolve Archetype org.apache.camel.archetypes:camel-archetype-java:2.12.1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact
```

Request help.

Answer (score 3):

Your Maven repository URL is wrong. Use the Remote Maven Default repository at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml. You can add or change repositories in the "Select an Archetype" dialogues. Choose "Configure..." and edit an existing catalog or add a new one with the URL given above.

Answer (score 0):

Best way i found it is to add a new remote catalog.
Open Eclipse ->Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Archetypes.
Add a new remote catalog using the file : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

This will add to you IDE all the updated catalogs including the one you need them for Camel.